# Form input validation in Angular 2(template driven)

Tags: angular

I would like to make these inputs to display a message such as "Name is required" when submitted(so the submit button is disabled until there is name inside). Is there perhaps a simple way to do it with Angular 2 Template Driven forms? I guess that I should provide some properties in form's HTML, and connect it to a component, but could not figure it out while following the samples in documentation. Appreciate all the help.

```
<form class="">
    <div>
        <p>Name:</p>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="link-input">
        <p>City:</p>
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <button 
        (click)="submitForm()">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **TEMPLATE DRIVEN FORMS**

I also having this question and i found answer and that i wanted to share with you.
I created a login form with validation which is look like as following:

### **login.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !username.valid }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            <img *ngIf="loading" src="loading.gif" />
            <a [routerLink]="['/register']" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

### **login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { AlertService, AuthenticationService } from '../services';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;
    returnUrl: string;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertService: AlertService) { }

    ngOnInit() {}

    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you if you need any help you can write me. I feel happy to help you. @Smithy i am also learning angular 2.

Comment: In your answer, Validation will not occur until the form is submitted. Have not you faced any issue while clicking on register link.

Comment: No, the link just redirects to a registration form.

Comment: I have the same form, i guess you copied it from a angular authentication tutorial, but i wanted to ask whether it has something to do with the backend login.component.ts code, as i removed the code and changed it to firebase authentication and now it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Your Html :

```
<form role="form" [formGroup]="inputForm" novalidate>
    <div>
        <p>Name:</p>
        <input
         formControlName="name"
         type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="link-input">
        <p>City:</p>
        <input
         formControlName="city"
         type="text">
    </div>

    <button 
        [disabled]="!inputForm.valid"
        (click)="submitForm()">
    </button>
</form>
```

Your Component:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class InputComponent  {   
   public inputForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  this.inputForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name:    new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  city:    new FormControl('', Validators.required),
   });
  }
//... codes..
}
```

Comment: Thanks again I am trying, is there perhaps a way to do it by importing only FormsModule? I just don't have enough experience to implement it with all this Angular2 stuff so it's difficult for me to understand :/ I would post a whole code here but it's quite long. Should I make the whole new component with the code inside(the code that you posted under Your Component)? I have an app.component, can I do it from there somehow?

Comment: yes , of course , the `InputComponent` that i'd posted is not necessary , just put that code in the component that is relevant to the HTML file of the two inputs (city & name) .. and do not forget to import what is above .. clear ?

Answer (score 2):

This makes sure that that the form has been touched (inputs have been changed) and that the name field is at least 1 letter long. You can do something similar for city.

Component:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class InputComponent  {   
  public inputForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.inputForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name:    new FormControl('', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
      city:    new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }
}
```

View:

```
<form [formGroup]="inputForm" novalidate>
  <p>Name:</p>
  <input placeholder="Exercise" formControlName="name">
  <div class="errorMsg" *ngIf="inputForm.get('name').touched && inputForm.get('name').status === 'INVALID'">
    Name is required</div>
  <p>City:</p>
  <input placeholder="Exercise" formControlName="city">
  <button [disabled]="!inputForm.valid || !inputForm.touched (click)="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The angular 2 form validation quite differs than what we have done in angular 1.
when you write form tag to the DOM angular 2 adds the ngForm and ngControl to it.
A button can be disabled by using angular2 property [disabled]. to keep button disabled you need to apply validation property to [disabled]. I have given one simple example which will give you form validation, input fields validation with pattern validation.
the button will be disabled until the form will be valid

In your HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(myForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!signinForm.controls['usermail'].valid && signinForm.controls['usermail'].touched}">
      <label>Email Address</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="email" [formControl]="signinForm.controls['usermail']">
      <span *ngIf="signinForm.controls['usermail'].hasError('required') && signinForm.controls['usermail'].touched && !signinForm.submitted" class="required pull-right">*Please Enter Email</span>
      <span *ngIf="signinForm.controls['usermail'].hasError('pattern') && signinForm.controls['usermail'].touched" class="required pull-right">*Invalid Email</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!signinForm.controls['userpass'].valid && signinForm.controls['userpass'].touched}">
       <label>Password</label>
       <input class="form-control" type="password" [formControl]="signinForm.controls['userpass']" (focus)="showErrorMessage=false">
        <span *ngIf="signinForm.controls['userpass'].hasError('required') && signinForm.controls['userpass'].touched && !signinForm.submitted" class="required pull-right">*Please Enter Password</span>
    </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pri mds_btn" [disabled]="!signinForm.valid">Login</button>       
</form>
```

In your Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './login.component.scss' ]
})
export class LoginComponent {
   myForm: FormGroup;

   emailRegex: any = '^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$';
    passRegex:any ='^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}$'; 

   constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {

      this.myForm = fb.group({
         'logmail': [ null, Validators.compose([ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailRegex) ]) ],
         'logpass': [ null, Validators.compose([ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.passRegex) ]) ]
      });

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((form: any) => {
   });
  }

  submitForm(lgvalue: any) {
       //do logic here after submitting the form

  }
}
```

in this example, I am using FormGroup directive of FormBuilder.The FormBuilder creates instances of FormGroup, which we refer to as a form. I am also subscribing to the form so that whenever the value entered in the input field the form will be subscribed.

I hope this will help you :)